# Please show indicator in question list to see which questions are community wiki

Tags: feature-request, questions, community-wiki

Is it possible to put an indicator in question list to see which questions are community wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already shown - where it would say who it was asked by and when, it says "community wiki" for CW questions. At least, it does if you're in the "questions" view rather than just the home page - I can't tell what happens on the home page as there are no CW questions there at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I think the missing bit of information there is: what problem are you trying to solve? If you don't want to "waste time" on discussion-esque questions, that should be fairly obvious from the question title.

I don't see a need for any additional UI here, personally; but if there is some *purpose*, feel free to elaborate...